# Perfomance issues Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'm building a website in Nuxt.js where I'm new in. It seems me like after every page route the side become slower. Especially the start page become very slow. I don't really have a clue what is going on. Could anybody give me a hint how to improve the perfomance?

Here is the site:
https://sz3app.bearhost.de/

Comment: Your browser (probably) has performance auditing tools. Try using those first

Comment: I tested it as you recommended. The site is running full of DOM Nodes. Is there a way to clean the DOM Noes after each route?